# How to remove rows in data frame of time series events if another specific event doesn't fall within a given threshold value?

Tags: r

This is my first time posting a question here so i apologize in advance if I did it wrong. now i'll try to explain my issue and provide a reproducible example. TIA

I have a data frame of when animals are detected at different sites. I want to eliminate rows from the detection file (df) for **only** site A if the individual animal wasn't detected at site B within a time frame ( 5 minutes). **I need to iterate this over every individual animal and across multiple sites**. my real data has many animals and over a million detection observations. I'm guessing this is going to need at least two for loops.

I've been able to find if the the exact time is in the second data frame but i don't know how to add a "threshold" so to speak around the times ( like 5 min)

Example:

```
obs.num<-1:20 # a simple observation number 
animal<-c(rep("RBT 1",10),rep("RBT 2",7) ,rep("RBT 3",2),"RBT 2") # a fake list of animal id's (my data has many)
now <- Sys.time()
ts <- seq(from = now, length.out = 16, by = "mins")
ts <- c(ts,seq(from=tail(ts,1), length.out = 4, by = "hour")) # create a fake series of time stamps 
df<-cbind.data.frame(obs.num,animal,ts) # make data frame 
df$site<-c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")# make a fake series of sites detection occured at 
str(df)
df # my example data frame

> df
   obs.num animal                  ts site
1        1  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:11:38    A
2        2  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:12:38    B
3        3  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:13:38    A
4        4  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:14:38    B
5        5  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:15:38    A
6        6  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:16:38    B
7        7  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:17:38    A
8        8  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:18:38    B
9        9  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:19:38    A
10      10  RBT 1 2018-11-30 15:20:38    B
11      11  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:21:38    A
12      12  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:22:38    B
13      13  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:23:38    A
14      14  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:24:38    B
15      15  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:25:38    A
16      16  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:26:38    B
17      17  RBT 2 2018-11-30 15:26:38    A
18      18  RBT 3 2018-11-30 16:26:38    B
19      19  RBT 3 2018-11-30 17:26:38    A
20      20  RBT 2 2018-11-30 18:26:38    B
```

In this example i would like to remove the entire row for observation 19.

In my larger real data set i've been able to do this to identify the rows/times where detection occurred at the exact same time at site A and another site but i'm really struggling with how find that position in the large data fram and how to replace the %in% with some sore of syntax to account for times that are not exact but very close (i.e. within 5 minutes)

```
animals<-unique(animal)
for (i in 1:length(animals)) {

which(df[df$animals==animals[i] & df$site=="A",]$ts %in% 
df[df$animals==animals[i] & df$site=="B",]$ts)

}
```

Thanks for any help and please ask if i can provide any more detail/clarification.

Updated Example (I want to be able to do this based on the detection for **each Individual animal**

In this example I still want observation 19 to be removed but the answer would not result in that based on the answer by @G. Grothendieck

```
df[21,]<-df[19,]
df$animal<-as.character(df$animal)
df[21,"animal"]<-"RBT 4"
df[21,"site"]<-"B"
df[21,"obs.num"]<-21
df$animal<-as.factor(df$animal)
df<-df[order(df$ts),]
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Define table `B` as those rows for site B and then join `df` to those those rows in `B` satisfying the condition.  Note that observation 19 is now eliminated.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("with B as (select * from df where site == 'B')
  select distinct df.* from df 
  join B on df.animal = B.animal and 
            B.ts - df.ts between -5 * 60 and 5 * 60
  order by 1")
```

giving:

```
   obs.num animal                  ts site
1        1  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:43:00    A
2        2  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:44:00    B
3        3  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:45:00    A
4        4  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:46:00    B
5        5  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:47:00    A
6        6  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:48:00    B
7        7  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:49:00    A
8        8  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:50:00    B
9        9  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:51:00    A
10      10  RBT 1 2018-12-03 16:52:00    B
11      11  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:53:00    A
12      12  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:54:00    B
13      13  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:55:00    A
14      14  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:56:00    B
15      15  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:57:00    A
16      16  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:58:00    B
17      17  RBT 2 2018-12-03 16:58:00    A
18      18  RBT 3 2018-12-03 17:58:00    B
19      20  RBT 2 2018-12-03 19:58:00    B
20      21  RBT 4 2018-12-03 18:58:00    B
```

### Note

Given that there were changes in the example in the question to be clear we used this in the example above:

```
obs.num<-1:20 # a simple observation number 
animal<-c(rep("RBT 1",10),rep("RBT 2",7) ,rep("RBT 3",2),"RBT 2") # a fake list of animal id's (my data has many)
now <- Sys.time()
ts <- seq(from = now, length.out = 16, by = "mins")
ts <- c(ts,seq(from=tail(ts,1), length.out = 4, by = "hour")) # create a fake series of time stamps 
df<-cbind.data.frame(obs.num,animal,ts) # make data frame 
df$site<-c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B")# make a fake series of sites detection occured at 
df[21,]<-df[19,] 
df$animal<-as.character(df$animal) 
df[21,"animal"]<-"RBT 4" 
df[21,"site"]<-"B" 
df[21,"obs.num"]<-21 
df$animal<-as.factor(df$animal) 
df<-df[order(df$ts),]
```

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck. your answer does work for the example I provided.I've never used sqldf. I looked into the cran a little bit.

Comment: Thanks @G. Grothendieck. your answer does work for the example I provided. I've never used sqldf. I looked into the cran a little bit. I'm concerned that the function doesn't have any reference to the individual column. If i updated my example to this and it would not eliminate observation 19, which is my goal. Perhaps i was not clear that i need to look at it by individual not just all detections.

Comment: If there was a different individual detected around the same time it would sill keep the detection row in the file.   </br>  df[21,]<-df[19,]
df$animal<-as.character(df$animal)
df[21,"animal"]<-"RBT 4"
df[21,"site"]<-"B"
df[21,"obs.num"]<-21
df$animal<-as.factor(df$animal)
df<-df[order(df$ts),]
df'

Comment: sorry for all the comments. i'm a novice when it comes to formatting these things. Any chance you have a suggestion for the updated problem? Please let me know how i vote/up vote so you get credit. thanks again

Comment: If you are asking to do this by animal then see the revised answer above.

Comment: Thanks!  Does anyone have a data.table solution for this? the sqldf() solution from @G.Grothendieck is taking a very long time

Comment: You can add an index using `create index` to speed it up.

Comment: I am not familiar with this. could you please provide an example?

Comment: Can you provide the dataset?